# Question in probability r defective items out of lot n

Tags: probability

I need help with this question:

A lot contains n articles. If it is known that r of the articles are defective and the articles are inspected in a random order, what is the probability that the kth article (k>=r) inspected will be the last defective one in the lot?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. On this site, you are expected to show what you have tried, what difficulties you are facing, so that help can be tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Let me take a concrete example, to illustrate the way to solve.

Total $= n = 10$, defectives $= r = 3$, place where last defective found $=k = 6$

We need $(3-1) = 2$ defectives in the first $5$ followed  by the final defective, against ${10\choose3}$ random places for the defectives, thus

$$Pr = \frac{{5\choose2}{1\choose1}}{10\choose3}$$

You should now be able to convert this to a general formula using $n,k,r$

[ Of course, ${1\choose1}$ can be omitted, was included to give better understanding ]

Comment: That really helped thank you!,

Answer (score 0):

You have $k$ slots to fill with $r$ defective pieces and $n-r$ good pieces. The last article needs to  be a defective one, so we fix one bad peice on that slot. This leaves us with $k-1$ slots to be filled with $r-1$ defective and $n-r$ good pieces to choose from. Can you try coming up with the probability using this information?